# rotate gear while no keeping it engaged with other gears

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, control-engineering, applied-mechanics, mechanisms

i am trying to build a toy where i need gear B to rotate when gear A rotates but when gear B rotate through a outforce gear A shouldnot rotate i hope that explains it well. (:
Both gears are on the same axle!

[image]

Comment: do you need both gears to be able to rotate in both directions.

Answer (score 2):

The component you are looking for is called a **freewheel**, a mechanism that only engages rotation in one direction and turns free in the other direction. A common application is the connection between rear-wheel and drivetrain of most bicycles. The image shows an example of how the freewheel mechanism can be designed.

[image: freewheel]

Further reading and image source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freewheel

Comment: A similar device can be found in starter motors used on cars. Also used for some tractor mounted lawn mowers and the drive on chainsaws...

Comment: It's called a one-way bearing or sprag clutch

Comment: OP does not really say he wants to rotate one way only. This might be it but needing  linkage that rotates both on rotating a in any direction and rotating only b one way or another would be very useful. Ive used a centrifugal clutch for this in the past but that only works with high enough speeds. Anyway id really like to find a better solution for this as i can think of top of my head 10 (oh no now 20) projects that would become way better if i could find one.

Comment: @joojaa Reading the question again, I see what you mean. Maybe OP will elaborate on what they are looking for.